# Google map, with admin lte , android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, web-applications

My question is, please I developed website for GPS app, but the main target is to develop android and IOS application, so I tried to develop android app webview so that it will displaying the pages in the app, but what I observed is Google map is not showing my current location, and if I try to navigate it will ask my to use the google map app, and once I tap on use the app, the it show error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pIWr.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your app probably does not have permission to use GPS.
So i would implement that first.